# Why I can't read the image?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I put a png photo into my project, and set the photo's build action to content.
Then I want to read this photo, so I write

```
System.Uri a = new System.Uri("/Images/photo.png");
BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
b.UriSource = a;
```

But the b is null!Why?
Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work!I edit my code to

```
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("Images/photo.png", UriKind.Relative));
BitmapImage noPhoto = new BitmapImage();
noPhoto.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
```